# CentOS Hibernate Expires

Tags: centos, power-management

I am able to Hibernate the machine.  If I power up within 30 minutes it performs as expected.  If I power up after a couple of hours it does a full reboot.

Is there some kinda expiration with hibernate?  What am I missing?  Any suggestion would be helpful.. I have no clue about where or what would cause this.

Linux 3.10, CentOS 7.4, Machine MSI PE70.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally figured it out by following directions from [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt)

Comment: What was the actual problem?